# Whats wrong in using Hard Waits in UI Automation scripts?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, wait, ui-automation

- I always keep on getting questions where people complaining explicit
  or fluent waits not working all the time so looking for some other
  solution. Well in most of the cases after putting a Hard Wait of 2 or
  3 sec problem gets resolved.
- But still the decision to make the scripts less faster does not makes
  your scripts less reliable after using hard waits of few seconds if
  they are really required is what I think.

  **I know the solution to my answer is not any code but want to really understand are they any serious hazards of using hard waits in Automation scripts?
  For me they are equally important to that of explicit and fluent waits.**

Comment: There are no harms to keep explicit `wait`.
In our project also we use explicit wait, it just consumes time, but it makes sure that our script is running properly.
We are not testing the `performance` of the application.

Comment: @KishanPatel : My question is not  towards explicit wait, well people love to use it , Kishan my question is usage of hard waits.

Comment: hard waits ? Is it thread.sleep() ?

Comment: Exactly is that I meant

Comment: I was talking about those wait only. It consumes time , but makes sure that our scripts work. SO no harm to keep such waits. It is just that we are extra safe with our scripts even though it takes time.

Comment: @ Kishan : Are you sure about my Question ?

Comment: There are detailed discussions of this all over the web. I suggest you google some and read them. This question is not a good fit for SO since it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Hard or implicit waits are undesirable because they add uneccassary execution time to a automation suite. If your test suite is small, is not run regularly or you are not under any time restraints then maybe implicit waits are acceptable.

In most real world scenarios quick test execution turnaround is highly desirable and adding a few 2/3 second waits adds up pretty quickly if you are executing tests on every commit to a branch or have a large test suite.

I would argue that if explicit waits are not working properly then they are either:

1. poorly written
2. not given enough time

The former is more likely.

Answer (score 1):

The hazard of using "Hard wait" or `Thread.Sleep()` more precisely is that **you're unsure if your condition is met**. In UI testing you mostly add sleeps so the UI will fulfill some condition such as Page to load, Element to appear / be enabled etc...

When you use `Thread.Sleep()` you need to set it to the maximum time so you'll be sure that your condition is met (even than you can't be sure about 'stress' situations - network load etc.). So you get wasting of your time and resources which make your automation **less scalable and less agile** (another hazard for some...)

So I would say if you **can't** add a condition to your wait `Thread.Sleep()` is  fine (though less readable), otherwise it's simply a bad practice.